# Ubicar cursor al inicio de un input tras evento focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una inquietud que me gustaría compartir con ustedes en aras de poder encontrar una solución.

Estoy utilizando React para la implementación de un proyecto y necesito en uno de mis formularios que al realizar el autofocus de uno de sus inputs el cual ya posee un valor inicial, **el cursor se ubique al inicio**; es decir antes del value inicial. Muestro parte del código para que tengan una idea de lo que deseo hacer.

**Constructor del componente**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {url: '.feeel.ai'};

    ...
}
```

En `this.state = {url: '.myurl.com'};` establezco el valor inicial del input. La idea es que al comenzar a escribir termine de esta forma el value del input: *urldeusuario.myurl.com*.

**Parte del render del componente donde deseo hacer el trabajo**

```
<input type="text"
       className="name-field-container label-input"
       placeholder="myURL"
       ref="url"
       value={this.state.url}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       onKeyUp={this.enterKeyPress}
       onFocus={this.onFocusValue}/>
```

Con `this.onFocusValue` invoco a la función que debería realizar el trabajo que deseo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto no es cuestión de React.js, es simple JavaScript. Lo que buscas se logra mediante `setSelectionRange`:

```js
document.getElementById("prueba").addEventListener("click", onFocusValue);


function  onFocusValue () {
      this.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="prueba" id="prueba">
```

Comment: (si no te parece mal hice una versión ejecutable. sientete libre de revertirlo si no te gusta)

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia, @lois6b.

Comment: Nada, así creo que es más claro para el usuario ^^  Un  saludo

Comment: Me ha funcionado a la perfeccion, muchas gracias.